# Phantom power and audio interfaces

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, microphones, homerecording

I am a guitar player and a vocalist. I want to record my acoustic guitar and singing with a microphone. Now that I have bought myself an inexpensive condenser microphone (Neewer NW-1500), I got to know that I'll have to use audio interface or some kind of phantom power while I use it with my laptop. I wanna know if the mixers or the audio interfaces only could do the work (without phantom power) or will I have to buy all of them (audio interface and the phantom power)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with only an interface because many interfaces include phantom power. Usually phantom power is included with interfaces and mixers. Very rarely do people buy a separate phantom power supply.

When you buy an interface, just make sure it also has phantom power. Most interfaces do.

Comment: This particular model seems to use 'plug in power' rather than true phantom, though it may be compatible with that as well.

Comment: @LaurencePayne It does support 48V phantom power: http://www.neewer.com/40085747.html If the asker has already decided to buy an interface or mixer, then they won't be able to use plug-in power with either of those, and they will have to use phantom power, but they shouldn't buy a separate phantom power supply, instead they should just be sure to buy a mixer or interface that includes phantom power. Also, most interfaces can mixer, but not as many mixers can double as interfaces. Note that with an interface, you **can** use this mic with a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

The Neewer NW-1500 appears to be provided with a 3.5mm TRS jack plug, which suggests it is designed for direct connection to a computer's Mic socket providing 'plug in power' (which is not 'phantom powering' as usually understood).   However, although the online documentation is sketchy, it seems possible that if the supplied cable is replaced with a standard XLR to XLR 'microphone cable' it will work with the 48v phantom power supplied by the XLR mic socket on most 'audio interfaces'.

This seems to be a very cheap item, more concerned with what it looks like than how it performs!  But sure, give it a try.  If the supplied cable into your computer's Mic socket works, you're good to go.